# Question about text graphics and audio clips. How do i input text from the audio filename?

Tags: premiere

Sorry if the title is confusing, but I have around 500 audio clips with 500 text/titles or whatever it's called. As you can see in the image, there are multiple audio files with text graphics overlapping them. Since I have so many, I want to be able to automatically take the filename for the audio  (such as “and” as shown in the image) and display it as text.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Premiere would be a pain in the rear for doing this. You should opt for after effects, create a text and set the text content as the filename using an expression. Then you can just copy+paste this for every file and the name will be applied automatically.
Open your text-layer, alt+click on the "source-text"-stopwatch to create an expression. In this, type

```
thisComp.layer(2).name
```

IMPORTANT: For the expression to work, the audio-file must be placed so that it's layer 2, i.e. under the text-layer. If you want to change the position of the layer, just put the place of it in the expression, replacing the "(2)".

Now all you have to do is copy and paste that text-layer containing the expression, and (if the sound-files are all in the same position in each comp) the text-layer will automatically change to the name of your file.

Comment: I think this is a good suggestion - can you add to your answer the right expression for doing this? Might be helpful for others who find this answer.

Comment: Good addition, added it.